# Unable to upload files through Filezilla FTP

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I recently purchased a new Alienware laptop. I've been unable to upload files to my hosted server through the FileZilla FTP client. Upon uploading a file, the connection times out, and a 0MB empty file typically uploads with a corresponding name. This issue must be client sided, as I am able to upload files utilizing my other computers.

Things I have tried doing to troubleshoot the issue include:

- Making sure there is enough space on the drive on my server
- Utilizing different FTP clients (WinSCP works perfectly)
- Making sure FileZilla runs in passive mode
- Disabling Windows Firewall

Answer (score 0):

Steps you may take in Filezilla FTP:

- In menu Edit, Settings, Connection, increase "Timeout in seconds" to 500
- In Site Manager, assure the the site's settings include
  Encryption as "Only use plain FTP (insecure)" and Logon type is "Normal".
  If this does not work, try to recreate the site anew with those settings.
- Turn on verbose debugging and enable the debug menu for getting a clue as to
  the cause of the problem. (Sometimes it starts working correctly with these settings
  and keeps on working when they are undone.)
  Include the relevant data in your post.